# How to specify an index in terraform replace

Tags: terraform

I'm attempting to force the replacement of a resource in terraform using the following command in PowerShell:

```
terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes["Default"].null_resource.tsdb
```

I receive the error:

```
| Error: Invalid force-replace address "module.visibility_scopes[Default].null_resource.tsdb"
│
│ Index brackets must contain either a literal number or a literal string.
```

I've also tried (resulting in the same error):

```
terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes[Default].null_resource.tsdb
terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes[""Default""].null_resource.tsdb
terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes[`"Default`"].null_resource.tsdb
```

This attempt

```
terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes[\"Default\"].null_resource.tsdb
```

Gives the error:

```
│ Error: Invalid force-replace address "module.visibility_scopes[\\Default\\].null_resource.tsdb"
│
│ This character is not used within the language.
```

How do I specify the index correctly?

Terraform version:

```
Terraform v1.6.5
on windows_amd64
```

Answer (score 1):

Ahh - this has nothing specifically to do with terraform. It's a PowerShell thing:

```
terraform apply -replace "module.visibility_scopes[\`"Default\`"].null_resource.tsdb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try one of the next way

1. terraform apply -replace 'module.visibility_scopes["Default"].null_resource.tsdb'
2. terraform apply -replace "module.visibility_scopes["Default"].null_resource.tsdb"
3. terraform apply -replace module.visibility_scopes["Default"].null_resource.tsdb

I hope this help you